# Debugging attached process with gdb - how to escape from a loop

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

I am debugging code that looks like this:

```
while (true){
   // do something ...
   size_t i = foo();  // <- bp set here
   if (flag_set) break;
}

// More code follows here ...
```

I want to break at the foo() function call, invoke it a few times and then jump out of the while loop completely (lets assume that we are guaranteed that the flag will be set - so we can break out of the loop.

How do I break out of the loop completely?. finish simply runs to the next iteration. What I want to do is to exit the current "code chunk" (in this case, the while loop)

Comment: Do you want to break out of the loop literally (as if you had a `break;` statement in your code)? Or just to instruct gdb to not stop again until it exits the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the advance command, which takes the same arguments as the break command.  Using your code as an example (but with line numbers added):

```
10 while (true){
11   // do something ...
12   size_t i = foo();  // <- bp set here
13   if (flag_set) break;
14 }
15 
16 // More code follows here ...
17 someFunction();
```

Say your original breakpoint on line 12 was breakpoint 1, and after breaking a few times you wanted to skip to line 17, you would type something like:

disable 1

advance 17

which would disable breakpoint 1 (so it doesn't get hit for the rest of the loop) and then keep executing the program until it hit line 17.

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint before the loop. Then cursor to the foo() call, and use `Debug|Run to Line`. This is so useful that I have dedicated a function key to it.

Answer (score 0):

Set a second breakpoint after the loop.  `disable` the breakpoint inside the loop.  `cont`.  `enable` the breakpoint again.

I don't know of any easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `jump` command.  Per `gdb` help, on this system at least:

```
jump -- Continue program being debugged at specified line or address
```

Comment: No no no -- that physically changes the Program Counter! I don't even know why they provide this feature, it's so dangerous.

Comment: But that is what @oompahloompah asked for:  "jump out of the while loop completely (lets assume that we are guaranteed that the flag will be set - so we can break out of the loop."

Comment: What oompahloompah wants is a way to execute the remaining iterations without stopping at the breakpoint every time. At least, that's how I read it. See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is **until** command. This is the easiest way to avoid stepping through the loop. From [gdb manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#Continuing-and-Stepping):

> Continue running until a source line past the current line, in the current stack frame, is reached. This command is used to avoid single stepping through a loop more than once. It is like the next command, except that when until encounters a jump, it automatically continues execution until the program counter is greater than the address of the jump.